# remove rows in dataframe which are not all 1 or all 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, rows

I need to retain rows in the dataframe which has all row values as 0 or all 1.

```
a = np.repeat(0,10)
b = np.repeat(1,10)
ab = pd.DataFrame({'col1':a,'col2':b}).transpose()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution is the following:

```
# pip install pandas

import pandas as pd

# create test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[0,0,0,0],'col2':[1,1,1,1],'col3':[0,1,0,1],'col4':['a','b',0,1],'col5':['a','a','a','a']}).transpose()
df
```

[image]

```
# filter rows of dataframe
df = df[df.eq(0).all(axis=1) | df.eq(1).all(axis=1)]
df
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question

Comment: This was actually what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

One option, get the diff and ensure the result is always 0:

```
import numpy as np
np.all(np.diff(ab.values, 1)==0, 1)
```

Output:

```
array([ True,  True])
```

Then use this to slice:

```
ab[np.all(np.diff(ab.values, 1)==0, 1)]
```

Other option, use `nunique`:

```
ab[ab.nunique(1).eq(1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this presently as it also works I guess..

```
    Df= Df[(Df.sum(axis=1)==0) | (Df.sum(axis=1)==Df.shape[1])]
```